# Can I use some client-side cache for 'Big Datas' dynamic visualisation on a Dashboard?

Tags: python, django, bigdata, bokeh, dashboard

Good afternoon people !

Programming language : Python.
Web Framework : Django.
Graphic framework : Bokeh.

Currently trying to set up a Dashboard-like application for my company where each factory would be able to upload their own csv-like data and have dynamic results presentation after data cleaning and processing, and some predictions from machine-learning if enough data is provided.

The dynamic part is mostly using widgets to let them choose how to visualize, what to visualize, different parts of the data analysis process etc... with either JS Callbacks of the Bokeh server functionality.

Until now I decided not to use DataBase Storage but server-side storage in different big CSV, it seems like I have faster access to those on server-side than filtering each time my tables for a given factory upload. Also thought about creating temporary tables/models but didn't feel it right.

Before getting into any hard time programming that, I'd like to know if there is any easy answer to my questions, didn't find suitable solution online regarding this, considering the fact that they might upload a bunch of CSV at once.

- Is there anyway to save all the data (after cleaned on the server) in client-side cache so I have to send it only one time and then just sending the adapted graph structures, which would take the data from client-side cache to display them ?
- Is there any smarter way to do so between JS callbacks and Bokeh Server ? The documentation didn't help me much to decide between them.

I am taking any tips, and thanks for your time.

Have a nice week-end !

Comment: not sure how readily it will be to simply upload a csv, but Apache Superset is a relatively easy and quick way to do some of the visualization, sharing, caching. if the CSV is not able to simply be uploaded, Superset uses sqlAlchemy and thus SQLite format is an option and it's quite simple.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look